# Some icons from XFCE4 panel missing

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, xfce-panel

I'm running Xubuntu 13.04 (xfce4-panel 4.10.0). The icons for Skype and Synapse are missing in the panel. Only a missing icon icon is shown.

[image]

The icons show correctly in the apps menu. I've tried reinstalling the programs and removing and adding them back to the panel, but to no avail. No errors shows up in the syslog.

Is there anything else I can try?

edit:

The icon theme is elementary Xfce. I noticed that switching to KDE-HiColor fixed the problem. But I don't really like that theme. Is there a way to add the icons to the elementary Xfce theme?

Using the icon pack suggested my M.HannySabbagh didn't work (still the same problem with missing icons).

On my other computer I'm running Xubuntu 12.10 with icon theme Tango. The Skype icon looks good on that computer, but trying the Tango theme on my 13.04 computer results in the same "icon missing" icon as the elementary Xfce theme.

Comment: What icon theme are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can install latest development packages for the elementary icons theme from the [elementary Xfce PPA (daily)](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/elementary-xfce) . If you still encounter issues, feel free to report them on the project's [GitHub tracker](https://github.com/shimmerproject/elementary-xfce).

To install the icons, as `root`:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:landronimirc/elementary-xfce
apt-get update
apt-get install xubuntu-icon-theme
```

Answer (score 0):

first, remove  elementary Xfce icons package from your system.
then download the icons from here:
https://github.com/shimmerproject/elementary-xfce/archive/master.zip
and put the "elementary-xfce" folder in /home/USER/.icons
and switch to it using xfce settings.
thanks.